# Get input value when clicking on button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, input, textbox, click

I knew how to fix this but right now I just don't remember. What I am doing is dynamically create two input elements: a text-box and a button. When I press on the button I want an alert with the text-box's value

```
var Form = {
    Create: function() {
        var Input = document.createElement('input');
            Input.type = 'text';
        document.body.appendChild(Input);

        var Button = document.createElement('input');
            Button.type = 'button';
            Button.value = 'Show Value';
        document.body.appendChild(Button);

        Button.onclick = function() {
            alert(Input.value);
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() { Form.Create(); }
```

When I click on the button I get an empty message, even if the text-box contains text. So, I want the function to get the content of the text-box in real-time but I just don't know how this was done.

Comment: what if you add the click before you append it to the body? I think the current code binds the click to the var `Button` which holds the element, not a selector to the element

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaQNS/

Comment: @Martijn: Event handlers are never bound to a selector. The `var Button` holds the element, and the event handler is bound to that.

Answer (score -1):

it seems that you are appending an other button

change this line :

```js
document.body.appendChild(LoginButton);
```

by this:

```js
document.body.appendChild(Button);
```